# Count number of unique values per row

Tags: r, count, row, unique

I want to count the number of unique values per row.

For instance with this data frame:

```
example <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,3,3,2,4,5), 
                  var2 = c(2,3,5,4,2,5), 
                  var3 = c(3,3,4,3,4,5))
```

I want to add a column which counts the number of unique values per row; e.g. 2 for the first row (as there are 2's and 3's in the first row) and 1 for the second row (as there are only 3's in the second row).

Does anyone know an easy code to do this? Up until now I only found code for counting the number of unique values per column.

Comment: ues `example <- cbind(example, apply(example, 1, function(x)length(unique(x))))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `apply` function returns a vector of the number of unique values in each row:

```
apply(example, 1, function(x)length(unique(x)))
```

You can append it to your data.frame using on of the following two ways (and if you want to name that column as `count`):

```
example <- cbind(example, count = apply(example, 1, function(x)length(unique(x))))
```

or

```
example$count <- apply(example, 1, function(x)length(unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a vectorized approach with `regex`.  After `paste`ing the elements of each row of the dataset (`do.call(paste0, ...`), match a pattern of any character, capture as a group (`(.)`), using the positive lookahead, match characters only if it appears again later in the string (`\\1` - backreference for the captured group and replace it with blank (`""`).  So, in effect only those characters remain that will be unique.  Then, with `nchar` we count the number of characters in the string.

```
example$count <- nchar(gsub("(.)(?=.*?\\1)", "", do.call(paste0, example), perl = TRUE))
example$count
#[1] 2 1 3 3 2 1
```

Comment: I upvoted it see this 2 years late!