# Assigning unique variable from a data.frame

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, unique, identity-column

This is a similiar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628384/count-number-of-unique-values-per-row-in-r) but my output results are different.

Take the data:

```
example <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,3,3,2,4,5), 
                  var2 = c(2,3,5,4,2,5), 
                  var3 = c(3,3,4,3,4,5))
```

Now I want to create `example$Identity` which take a value from 1:x for each unique var1 value

I have used

```
example$Identity <- apply(example[,1], 2, function(x)(unique(x)))
```

But I am not familiar with correct formatting `function()`

The output of `example$Identity` should be 1,2,2,1,3,4

Comment: Do you need `1:n` groups based on `var1` only? Does this work for you: `as.numeric(as.factor(example$var1))`?

Comment: Yes, you answered just before the proposed answer, do you want to write and i will select and close the question

Comment: I don't mind mark as answer Jaap's proposed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
example$Identity <- as.numeric(as.factor(example$var1))
```

will give you the desired result:

```
> example$Identity
[1] 1 2 2 1 3 4
```

By wrapping the `as.factor` in `as.numeric` it starts counting the factor levels with `1` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `match`

```
example$Identity <- with(example, match(var1, unique(var1)))
```

If the values are sorted as in the vector, `findInterval` can be also used

```
findInterval(example$var1, unique(example$var1))
#[1] 1 2 2 1 3 4
```

Comment: nice to see the flexibility and diversity of the R language +1

Comment: @Jaap Thanks, my first option would be also `factor(`