# Error ifelse statement, fread and within function: If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep()

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I'm trying to do the following ifelse statement. My purpose is to create a new column in which I can identify individuals that have the same value in four columns.

```
example<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:2,20,rep=TRUE)))

within(example,example$X <- ifelse(example$X1!=example$X2,NA,
                                 ifelse(example$X2!=example$X3,NA,
                                        ifelse(example$X3!=example$X4,NA,example$X1))))
```

In my case, the four columns are years. I want to identify panel individuals. With my data the code is the following:

```
within(educ_1,educ_1$X <- ifelse(educ_1$N2014!=educ_1$N2015,NA,
                                 ifelse(educ_1$N2015!=educ_1$N2016,NA,
                                   ifelse(educ_1$N2016!=educ_1$N2017,NA,educ_1$N2014))))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , nl, value = list(educ_1 = list(PER_ID = c(9.95048326217056e-313,  : 
>     Supplied 67 items to be assigned to 14191305 items of column 'educ_1'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

One thing though is that I used fread function to import the data, since it is about 14millions observations then I thought it would be more efficient.

Any thoughts or suggestions about the syntax or the error? What should I do?. Why does it work with simple statements but not with my own data?

[output of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FGsv.png)

Comment: Use random seed for reproducible input example `set.seed(1); example <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:2,20,rep=TRUE)))` then provide expected output.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43580891/680068

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` syntax you could do:

```
setDT(example) # Shouldn't be necessary if you used fread() to import the data
example[, 
        X := uniqueN(unlist(.SD)) == 1, 
        by = 1:nrow(example),
        .SDcols = patterns("X[0-9]")]
```

Comment: Thanks ! Elegant and simple solution. PS: I need to work more on data.table it is quite powerful.